# Remove the additional ranges in MVC chart and show a label for each point

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, charts

I want to create a line chart like [this](https://media-www-asp.azureedge.net/media/38741/ch07_charts-04.jpg) using the ASP.Net MVC chart helper.

I am using the following code to create the line chart.

```
new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
    .AddTitle("Chart Title")
    .AddSeries(
    chartType: "Line",      
        name: "Employee",
        xValue: new[] { "Peter", "Andrew", "Julie", "Mary", "Dave" },
        yValues: new[] { "2", "6", "4", "5", "3" })
```

This is the output I am getting the output like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYol3.png)

I am getting an unwanted extra column for X axis before the first value (Peter) and after the last value (Dave).

I am also unable to display the value for each points in the graph. For example I would like to display "2" for data point corresponding to  Peter, "6" for the data point corresponding to Andrew" as shown in the first figure. How can I get that format?